Jest mocking core NodeJs module
I'm trying to write an abstraction layer for an Electron application that runs in a Node (v20) environment. This layer will make it so that there is only one access point to the file system for the whole application. I'm running into an issue where I've created mocks for the core NodeJs os module, but they are picked up in an unexpected way (Or I might not understand how Jest handles mocking).
My repository is available, should anyone want to investigate the setup, but I'll highlight the important stuff below.
The code is running with the following setup:

NodeJs v20.15.1

NPM v10.7.0

Jest v~27.7.0


It doesn't matter if I use swc or tsc to compile the code, nor does it matter if I use ts-jest or babel, the results are the same. Also doesn't matter if I use regular function declaration instead of anonymous functions like described below.
What I'm expecting is that the mock that I've set up for the build-in os module is being picked up the same way the mocks for the process and fs/promises are handled.
I've created helper functions that use the "platform" function from the build-in os Node module, to indicate on which operating system the app is running as follows:
// <projectRoot>/lib/src/lib/utils/os.ts
import { platform } from 'os';

// These functions don't respect the mock that is set up and the "platform" call 
// actually returns whatever the actual operating system is that the code is executed on.
export const isRunningOnWindows = () => platform() === 'win32':

export const isRunningOnMac = () => platform() === 'darwin';

I've created some functionality to mock, switch and verify the current platform during a test, which looks like as follows:
// <projectRoot>/lib/src/testing/mocks/os.ts
export type ValidOS = 'darwin' | 'win32';

export let operatingSystem: ValidOS = 'darwin';

export const withOS = (os: ValidOS) => operatingSystem = os;

I've created the following to mock the os module manually, which should be automatically picked up by Jest. The folder that contains the manual mocks (__mocks__) is also located besides the node_modules folder.
// <projectRoot>/__mocks__/os.js
const { operatingSystem } = require('../lib/src/testing/mocks/os.ts');

const osMock = jest.createMockFromModule('os');

osMock.platform = jest.fn(() => operatingSystem);

module.exports = osMock;

My test suite looks like as follows:
// <projectRoot>/lib/src/lib/utils/os.spec.ts
import { withOS, ValidOS } from '@/testing';
import { isRunningOnMac, isRunningOnWindows } from './os';

jest.mock('os');

describe('OS Utils', () => {
    function setupTest(os?: ValidOS) {
        if (os) withOS(os);
    }

    it('should detect it is running on Windows', () => {
        setupTest('win32');

        // Using the "platform" function here does return the value that is set up
        // with the mocking functionality.
        // console.log(platform());

        expect(isRunningOnMac()).toBe(false);
        expect(isRunningOnWindows()).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should detect it is running on macOS', () => {
        setupTest();

        expect(isRunningOnMac()).toBe(true);
        expect(isRunningOnWindows()).toBe(false);
    });
});

